# Filter values in pandas dataframe based on complex columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
dict = {'trade_date': {1350: 20151201,
  6175: 20151201,
  3100: 20151201,
  5650: 20151201,
  3575: 20151201,
     1: 20170301,
     2: 20170301},
 'comId': {1350: '257762',
  6175: '1038328',
  3100: '315476',
  5650: '658776',
  3575: '329376',
     1: '123456',
     2: '987654'},
 'return': {1350: -0.0018,
  6175: 0.0023,
  3100: -0.0413,
  5650: 0.1266,
  3575: 0.0221,
  1: '0.9',
  2: '0.01'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

the expected output should be like this:
dict2 = {'trade_date': {5650: 20151201,
     1: 20170301},
 'comId': {5650: '658776',
     1: '123456'},
 'return': {5650: 0.1266,
  1: '0.9'}}
```

I need to filter it based on the following condition: for each `trade_date` value, I want to keep only the top 20% entries, based on the value in column `return`. So for this example, it would filter out everything but the company with `comId` value `658776` and `return` value `0.1266`.

Bear in mind there might be `trade_dates` with more companies associated to them. In that case it should round that up or down to the nearest integer. For example, if there are 9 companies associated with a date, 20% * 9  = 1.8, so it should only keep the first two based on the values in column `return`.

Any ideas how to best approach this, I'm a bit lost?

Comment: @A.N. can you please provide an expected Output more clear.  Like a Dataframe or something????

Comment: it can have multiple values, so I can group by it. I'm interested in the top 20% companies by ```trade_date``` filtered by the ```return``` column. I'll update with a desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
df\
.groupby("trade_date")\
.apply(lambda x: x[x["return"] >
    x["return"].quantile(0.8, interpolation="nearest")])\
.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby().transform` to get the threshold for each row. This would be a bit faster than `groupby().apply`:

```
thresholds = df.groupby('trade_date')['return'].transform('quantile',q=.8)
df[df['return'] > thresholds]
```

Output:

```
      trade_date   comId  return
5650    20151201  658776  0.1266
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary variable storing only the rows with the same trade_date. Then use this:
df.sort_values(by='return', ascending=False)
and then remove the bottom 80%.
Loop through all possible dates and everytime you get the 20%, append them to a new dataframe.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to improve your answer. It lacks details and formatting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).